# Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

Tags: postgresql, syntax

I have a database query that is failing for some reason and I cannot find why! Here is the query `pg_query ($conn, 'SELECT ref from music
    ORDER BY artist WHERE ref=$ref')`

and this is the output:

`Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE" LINE 2: ORDER BY artist WHERE ref=3 ^ in /berw/homes1/t/tor10/public_html/cs25010/basket.php on line 44`

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: `order by` comes after `where`.

Comment: be careful of SQL injection, check pg_query_params()

Answer (score 0):

try this

You need to Use `Where Clause` Before `Order BY Clause`

```
pg_query ($conn, 'SELECT ref from music  WHERE ref=$ref ORDER BY artist')
```

EDIT:

IT seems that your using `$ref` as string then enclose it with single quotes

```
pg_query ($conn, 'SELECT ref from music  WHERE ref='.$ref.' ORDER BY artist')
```

Comment: And explain that the ORDER BY-statement has to come after the WHERE-statement....

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, however I am now getting a new error:

Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$" LINE 1: SELECT ref from music WHERE ref=$ref ORDER BY artist ^